# Having trouble with Bootstrap column order with media queries

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, media-queries, xhtml

I am building a template for a site and it needs 4 columns.  In desktop mode, or anything above tablet width, it should display all 4 columns though the outer 2 are only for padding.  When in mobile mode, the outer 2 are set to disappear, but I need the middle two to reverse their order.  I tried setting the 'col-' setting to reverse when under 480px, but it isn't working.  I'd appreciate someone looking over my work.

```
  HTML
```

```
    <div id="inus1" class="fk-row row">
  <div data-text="text" align="center" id="inyb3" class="fk-col order-1">
  </div>
  <div align="center" id="i80rh" class="fk-col order-2 order-xs-2">
    <div id="ifo6l">
      <div id="iq1zf" class="fk-headline">Thank you for your purchase!
      </div>
      <div data-text="text" id="ihleo">Order {{orderId}}
        <div draggable="true" id="i6myy-2-2">
          <div draggable="true" id="ii502-2-2-2">
            <b data-text="text">
              <span data-text="text" id="ix3j4">Thank you {{firstName}} {{lastName}}!</span>
            </b>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <iframe frameborder="0" type="map" name="map" address="" zoom="1" maptype="q" id="in2gu" src="https://maps.google.com/maps?&amp;z=1&amp;t=q&amp;output=embed"></iframe>
  </div>
  <div align="center" id="i33dp" class="fk-col order-3 order-xs-1">
    <table id="orderSummaryTable" class="w-100">
      <thead id="iweztk">
        <tr id="ikyi1h">
          <th colspan="3" id="i10uii">
            <span data-text="text" id="iqvl9r">Order Summary</span>
          </th>
        </tr>
        <tr id="ieggiv">
          <th id="inwrj">
            <span data-text="text" id="ipokfh">Item</span>
          </th>
          <th id="i259c">
            <span data-text="text" id="i5gfso">Quantity</span>
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="items-list">
        <tr>
          <td class="cell cell-items-list">
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div align="center" id="ijiyf" class="fk-col order-4">
  </div>
</div>
```

```
  CSS (just the media query)
```

```
    @media (max-width: 480px){
  #in2gu{
    width:615px;
    height:350px;
  }
  #i80rh{
    width:100%;
  }
  #i33dp{
    width:100%;
  }
  #inyb3{
    display:none;
  }
  #ijiyf{
    display:none;
  }
  #in2gu{
    width:615px;
    height:350px;
  }
}
```

Comment: Create a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap comes with ordering utilities. Try them by appending `order-0, order1, etc.` to your elements

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/#order